# Set length conditions on text column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I set a minimum length on MySQL text column?

I want the column length (after trimming probable spaces) to be for example 32 characters.

Comment: For storage or for show ( in select  ) ???

Answer (score 2):

if your purpose is storage

You cannot set a minimum length for a `column` in MySQL.

you can only set MAX length for a `column` for example `VARCHAR(max)`

you must use PHP to limit the length. It's better use validations in Model

Answer (score 0):

Like this probably:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(w,' ',''),32)  FROM
(SELECT 'How can I set a minimum length on MySQL text column?' AS w) a
```